# VPN SSL/IPsec Server Behind NAT

Tags: vpn, nat

Is it possible to have the VPN Server behind NAT and SSL/IPSec clients connect to it ?

Which ports will I have to forward ?

Comment: Again, this depends on your vendor, but for IPSEC traffic, the [ESP packets (IP type 50)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233256) may be a bit troublesome, so you may want to provide additional details.

Comment: @JamesShewey ESP Packets are the *only* IPsec packets that can possibly travel through NAT devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Really need more detail to answer definitively, but generally...

For IPsec, you will need to forward ISAKMP (UDP/500) and NAT-T (UDP/4500).  Potentially other ports if you've configured your VPN to tunnel on other, non-standard, ports than these two.  Also worth pointing out, most IPsec implementations today use ESP (IP Protocol 50), which *is able* to pass through NAT.  Unlike its counter-part AH (IP Protocol 51), which is entirely incompatible with *any* sort of NAT.

For SSL/TLS, you will need to forward TCP/443 through your NAT device.  Unless, again, your implementation is specifically listening on another port.

All of the above is assuming your SSL Server/VPN Termination point is behind a PAT IP (many to one NAT).  If, however, you are simply behind a PAT and making connections outbound to a static/public VPN/SSL IP, then you typically won't have to do anything special, unless your IT/Network administrators lock down your outbound traffic as well (which isn't terribly uncommon, but I wouldn't quite call it common).

Comment: It is important to note that while ESP CAN be routed, not all devices WILL route it and you mileage will vary. You will need to check with your device vendor. For example, F5's do not support NATing this traffic and has to decrypt, then re-encrypt traffic to proxy. SonicWALL does support this, but requires special rules to catch IP type 50. This is why I suggest providing details about the equipment you are working with as someone may be able to point you to a specialized configuration guide.

Answer (score 0):

For sslvpn that really depends on your vendor, but i'd say TCP/10443

because that's the most used port for sslvpn by default.

For IPsec you'd want UDP/500 and UDP/1500

j,

Comment: TCP/10443 is by no means an industry standard.  And for IPsec, UDP/500 is correct (ISAKMP port), but UDP/1500 is incorrect.  You may have been thinking of NAT Traversal, which is UDP/4500.

Answer (score 0):

In scenario where server is behind NAT I would try to put server in DMZ. For IPSec behind NAT roadwarrior scenario might work. StrongSwan provides information how to configure IPsec on server and client in roadwarrior scenario on [page](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan#roadwarrior-case), but this is in case where client is behind NAT, not server. More details about [NAT-T](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1x49/topics/concept/ipsec-nat-traversal-understanding.html).